# RedirectToAction from Edit page back to Index page with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am basically trying to go back to the page I came from. For example from `https://po/POes/Edit/1321` back to `https://po/?pg=10` after saving changes instead of being redirected back to page 1?

To make this question clearer: how do I pass an id and page number from the edit page and get to edit httppost controller so that I can redirect the user back to the index page 10?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using POV1.Data;
using POV1.Models;

namespace POV1.Controllers
{
    public class POesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MVCDemoDbContext _context;

        public POesController(MVCDemoDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }        

        public IActionResult Index(int pg = 1)
        {
            List<PO> po = _context.POT.OrderByDescending(b => b.Id).ToList();
            const int pageSize = 10;
            if (pg < 1)
                pg = 1;

            int recsCount = po.Count();
            int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            ViewBag.Greeting = hour < 12 ? "Good Morning" : "Good Afternoon";
            var pager = new Pager(recsCount, pg, pageSize);

            int recSkip = (pg - 1) * pageSize;
            var data = po.Skip(recSkip).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList();

            this.ViewBag.Pager = pager;
            
            return View(data);
        }
   
        // POST: POes/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id,    [Bind("Id,Supplier,Description,DateTimeItemReleased,Employee,Additional")] PO pO)
        {
            if (id != pO.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(pO);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!POExists(pO.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = pO.Id });
            }
            return View(pO);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following:

```cs
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = pO.Id });
```

Comment: FWIW I find myself cringe when I see names like `pO` or `POesController` in code.  Use good names like `purchaseOrder` or `postOffice` or something that makes sense now and then 2 years from now to someone else.   What is is Poe? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Allan_Poe

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm glad you asked about POE. It's a very important acronym in our business. POE stands for Power over Ethernet, which is a technology that allows devices to receive power and data through the same cable. Just kidding! That's a different POE. My POE stands for purchase order, and the es part is something VS added for fun. I don't know why they did that, maybe they like Spanish or something. I know it's confusing, but don't worry, I'm still learning this stuff too. I'll make sure to remember it for the future.

Comment: Shouldn't you redirect with parameter pg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing the concept of page number with id here.  While you MIGHT be able to do that you would need to either track the page number (say in a ViewBag or a proper ViewModel with appropriate properties) OR do some complex logic to find the page the item falls within then send that to the Index view with the proper overloaded signature.

Or just use a pagination object:

```
public class Pagination
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    public int PageSize{ get; set; } = 10;
    public int TotalItems{ get; set; }
    public bool SortDirection{ get; set; } = SortDirection.Ascending;
}

public enum SortDirection { Ascending, Descending }
```

then redirect

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new Pagination() { PageSize = pageSize, PageNumber = pageNumber });
```

to something like:

```
public IActionResult Index(PaginationObject paginationObject)
{
     // rest here to returned the list of page items
}
```